# Why isn't this code working? (edited)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
using namespace std;

void Fight(int row) {

    srand((int)time(NULL));
    char arr[100][100];

    for (int a = 0; a < row; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < row; b++) {
            if (rand()%2 == 0) {
                arr[a][b] == '|';
            }
            else {
                arr[a][b] == 'p';
            }
            cout << arr[a][b];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main() {

    int num;

    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    cin >> num;

    Fight(num);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the result is chinese characters printed

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: `arr[a][b] == '|'` is a worthless equivalence test and not an assignment. Likewise with `arr[a][b] == 'p';`. Both would be flagged by even the most fledgling of compilers if you bothered to enable your warnings and actually read them.

Comment: And do you really need an array (or rather an array of arrays) here? Can't you just print the character directly instead of storing it in an array that will never (as far as we know) be used again?

Comment: If you want to update your question, then *edit* it. Below the tags there is a line with links. The second one of those is [`edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49747150/edit).

Comment: When your post exactly falls into *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*.

Answer (score 1):

Change `arr[a][b] == '|';` to `arr[a][b] = '|';` and `arr[a][b] == 'p';` to `arr[a][b] = 'p';`.

The == operator checks whether LHS = RHS. What you want to do is assign '|' or 'p' to the specific index. The assignment operator is '='.

For more info [check this link](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/what-is-difference-between-assignment-and-equalto-operator.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. It worked. but after changing '|' to '○', it doesnt worked. Is there any good way to solve this?

Comment: @Secret you mean to say on changing '|' to 'o', the code doesn't work?

Comment: '○' (U+25CB) may or may not fit into a single `char` depending on what encoding you're using.

Comment: how can i put '●' and '○' into an array? like the above p did. We dont have any methods for that? i hop you could understand my question

Comment: @Secret If you want to use any characters outside of ASCII you'll need to use a type other than `char` to store them.

Comment: I can't find any data type which can print extended bytes of special character.